# What's the standard used by yum prompt "Is this ok [y/N]:"?

Tags: command-line, standard

I can see that uppercase letter means default here. Is there a standard for this? I'd like to read the full standards.

Comment: I dont know of a a written standard, But historically the uppercased letter is the default on y/n choices. It's always been that way as far back as i can remember.

Comment: I think the name of the involved "standard" is "Common sense."  What makes you think there are standards for everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a written standard, it is, however, a *de facto* standard, meaning it had been used and found useful, so it came to be the common way to do things.

As Alex said - from common sense.